# Rails link_to syntax error: unexpected ',', expecting ')'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-rails

I recently attempted to add bootstrap-sass to my rails app, and it seemed to have broken all my links (the links were fully functional before installing the bootstrap-sass gem).  I am using ruby 1.8.7.

A sample link I have is:

```
<%=link_to image_tag ("right_arrow.png", :size => '20x20'), project_step_path(@project, @step.number+1) %>
```

The error I am getting is:

```
syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')' ...o(image_tag ("right_arrow.png", :size => '20x20'), project_s...
```

Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is an extra-space after image_tag.

```
image_tag ("right_arrow.png", :size => '20x20')
```

It should be

```
image_tag("right_arrow.png", :size => '20x20')
```